# Unable to Center InteractiveViewer and panning in Flutter Web app

Tags: image, flutter, center

I am try to display list of images in interactiveviewer so I can pan in both direction. Even after placing inside the Center widget, the interactiveviewer is aligned left. Tried to set the constrained property as true and added a overflowbox with alignment in topcenter as did in flutter source. But, I can't pan the list of images and zoom in/ out to old position. This issue is only in Flutter Web app.

Kindly help me out in resolving this.

```
Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          constrained: false,
          child: Column(
            key: _columnKey,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
                10, (int index) {
              return Image.asset('assets/image.png');
            }),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 5):

Bit late but hope this helps you and if not, someone else.

While alignment for InteractiveViewer with `constrained: false` appears to be always top-left (and there isn't an alignment property yet), there is a way I used to center a child:

```
Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
          constrained: false,
          child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    key: _columnKey,
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(
                        10, (int index) {
                      return Image.asset('assets/image.png');
                    }),
                  ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Basically, you create a container the size of your window within the interactive viewer (which InteractiveViewer will position top-left) then center whatever you want within that container.

This is my first answer on StackOverflow so apologies if anything isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

This is "intended" behaviour according to the Flutter team, and you can see it in the code for the `InteractiveViewer` widget that it creates an `OverflowBox` with alignment set to top-left. You can comment this out in your local files to see that the `InteractiveViewer` will be centered if you do. However, to actually make the widget centered properly, one solution (like I ended up doing) is to recreate the `InteractiveViewer` and edit the code you need.

See also: [InteractiveViewer with constrained: false ignores Center widget and alignment #90517](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90517)

Answer (score 1):

In my case worked:

```
InteractiveViewer(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            minScale: myMinScale,
            maxScale: myMaxScale,
            constrained: false,
            child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: buildImage(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a trasformation matrix as below:

```
    const zoomFactor = 1.0;
    final xTranslate = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2;
    final yTranslate = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4;

    var transformationController = TransformationController();
    transformationController.value.setEntry(0, 0, zoomFactor);
    transformationController.value.setEntry(1, 1, zoomFactor);
    transformationController.value.setEntry(2, 2, zoomFactor);
    transformationController.value.setEntry(0, 3, -xTranslate);
    transformationController.value.setEntry(1, 3, -yTranslate);    

    Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          transformationController: viewTransformationController,
          constrained: false,
          child: Column(
            key: _columnKey,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
                10, (int index) {
              return Image.asset('assets/image.png');
            }),
          ),
        ),
      )
```